# Removing the gear shift knob on my 96 pontiac

Tags: pontiac, grand-prix, shifter

Does anybody know how to remove the gear shift knob on a 96 pontiac grand prix?

Comment: pull, twist or undo the locking nut is most common.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If this is a floor shifter, I believe there is a flat pin accessed from the back side (near the console). Look for a slot down by where your fingers rest while shifting. Help it out with a small flat screwdriver.